# Convert datetime format from DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM to DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM

Tags: bash, datetime, awk, sed

I want to convert the datetime format from `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM` to `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM` in bash. The input is taken from an environment variable `$INPUT_DATETIME` and the output is set to `$OUTPUT_DATETIME`.

For ex,

```
    $ export INPUT_DATETIME="01-10-2021 00:05"
    $ echo $OUTPUT_DATETIME
      01/10/2021 00:05
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command tr in order to change each dash character into a slash.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_DATETIME="01-10-2021 00:05"
echo $INPUT_DATETIME
OUTPUT_DATETIME= echo "$INPUT_DATETIME" | tr - /
echo $OUTPUT_DATETIME
```

Comment: If you copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you about some of the problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ INPUT_DATETIME="01-10-2021 00:05"
$ OUTPUT_DATETIME="${INPUT_DATETIME//-/\/}"
$ echo "$OUTPUT_DATETIME"
01/10/2021 00:05
```